# How to put status bar icons back to the right in Firefox 6

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, statusbar

I'm using the Status-4-Evar extension in Firefox 6 to display the status bar like in Firefox 3. It used to have the link under the cursor to the left, and the icons (Firebug, etc.) to the right.

The problem is that I recently added another extension that messed up the status bar. It basically put all the status bar icons to the left and made the link under the cursor disappear. So I've deleted the extension.

However, the status bar didn't come back as it previously was. Now all the icons are still on the left, which means the link under the cursor doesn't show up at all (I suppose the label's container has a width of 0). Does anybody know how to bring it back? Maybe some parameter in about:config? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Status-4-Evar, restart FF and reinstall ?

Comment: Please include a screen capture and highlight the problem.  Also, if you can fake a picture of what you want, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but:

The thing with Firefox is that you can right-click on any bar having buttons, then choose `Customize`, and now you can add new buttons, or move the existing ones (just drag & drop them). The ones from Status-4-Evar (including the status text container) are included.

You can move buttons between different bars etc.

"Status Text" element has flexible width, so if it is removed, then all the icons like Firebug etc. go to the left accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you've already tried uninstalling your Status-4-Eva add-on and reinstalling it, then I'd recommend you try either -

**FF Menu > Options > Toolbar Layout > Scroll through the icons & look for the Status Text one** & place it back on your status bar.

Or

**FF Menu > Options > Toolbar Layout > Restore Default Set**

Perhaps experiment in Safe mode. Close your firefox and copy and paste "firefox -safe-mode" & run it in Run with "MenuKey + R" or press the windows key and type Run in the search bar.

Try resetting the toolbars and controls in safe mode see what happens.

Could you clarify this "link under the cursor" is actually the Status Text? That's the only one that makes sense, since removing it forces the Progress bar, download & addon icons to shift all the way to the left of the status bar. Otherwise, I have no idea what you're referring to.

Failing all of this, you can always **uninstall Firefox** and reinstall it with little setup time. I recommend you sync you bookmarks to an account & typing down all your addon names so you don't miss any (except the one that possibly screwed your status bar).

Also, you should let firefox keep updating. You probably do but I just thought it'd be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're looking for the status bar? I think you might actually be referring to the "Add-on" bar. Right click in the tab section at the top of your window and ensure the **Add-on Bar** is checked.

Comment: @laurent Sorry about my previous answer. Misunderstood your question. Have updated since.